# Binning variable by set number of observations

Tags: r

Quick question. I am binning a variable in a number of different ways for exploratory data analysis. Let's say I have a variable called `var` in data.frame `df`.

```
df$var<-c(1,2,8,9,4,5,6,3,6,9,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,2,3,4,6,1,2,3,7,8,9,0)
```

So far, I've employed the following approaches (code below):

```
#Divide into quartiles
df$var_quartile <- with(df, cut(var, breaks=quantile(var, probs=seq(0,1, by=.25)), include.lowest=TRUE))
# Values of var_quartile
> [0,3],[0,3],(7.25,9],(7.25,9],(3,5],(3,5],(5,7.25],[0,3],(5,7.25],(7.25,9],[0,3],(3,5],(3,5],(5,7.25],(5,7.25],(7.25,9],(7.25,9],[0,3],[0,3],(3,5],(5,7.25],[0,3],[0,3],[0,3]

#Bin into increments of 2
df$var_bin<- cut(df[['var']],2, include.lowest=TRUE, labels=1:2)
# Values of var_bin
> 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 1
```

The last thing that I'd like to do is bin the variable into sections of 10 observations after it has been sorted in chronological order. This is an identical approach to splitting after finding the median (counting up to the middle observation), only I want to count in 10-observation increments.

Using my example, this would split `var` into the following sections:

```
0,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3
4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,6,7
7,8,8,8,9,9,9
```

**N.B. -- I need to run this operation in very large datasets (usually 3-6 million observations in wide form).**

How do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide reproducible data.

Comment: @roody I think you'll find a lot of utility in the 'plyr' package for work like this.  You can use the function 'ddply' with the 'mutate' function to create various new columns for your bin idexes. You can also use the rolling functions in the 'zoo' package for grouping observations by 10.

Comment: What is the desired outcome if the data looks like: `var <- c( rep(1, 11), rep(2, 3), rep(3, 9), rep(4,20) )`  or even `sample(1:10, 100, repl=TRUE)`, since I'm quite sure that there will be some of those values with counts greater than 10.

Comment: @Dinre - Thanks so much! The one catch is that I'm doing this with huge datasets, which `ddply` seems to choke on, so I usually use data.table.

Comment: @DWin - Is my example sufficient?

Comment: @roody If you're using large datasets, you should definitely put that info up in your question.  As the datasets start getting larger, the methods for dealing with them usually require more creativity and need more streamlining.  There are a lot of common solutions that probably won't work for you, and you might as well weed out those answers from the start.  I still think you'll be best served by creating binning variables, but you'll want to look for vectorized solutions rather than looping solutions (like 'plyr').

Comment: @roody By the way, for your binning variables, you're going to want to specify them as stand-alone variables and not as new columns for your data (as you did in the example with `df$var_bin <- ...`).  New columns require a completely new memory allocation for the whole data frame and will often cause memory slowdowns, if not errors, when you're working with large data frames.  The R Inferno has a good chapter on how to think about this, if you want more in-depth info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
vec <- c(1,2,8,9,4,5,6,3,6,9,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,2,3,4,6,1,2,3,7,8,9,0) # your vector

nObs <- 10 # number of observations per bin

# create data labels
datLabels <- ceiling(seq_along(vec)/nObs)[rank(vec, ties.method = "first")] 


# test data labels:
split(vec, datLabels)

$`1`
 [1] 1 2 3 3 2 3 1 2 3 0

$`2`
 [1] 4 5 6 6 4 5 6 7 4 6

$`3`
 [1] 8 9 9 8 9 7 8 9
```

Comment: (+1) very nice use of `rank`. I'll remember this!

Answer (score 8):

`cut_number()` from **ggplot2** is designed to cut a numeric vector into intervals containing equal numbers of points.  In your case, you might use it like so:

```
library(ggplot2)
split(var, cut_number(var, n=3, labels=1:3))
# $`1`
#  [1] 1 2 3 3 2 3 1 2 3 0
# 
# $`2`
# [1] 4 5 6 6 4 5 6 4 6
# 
# $`3`
# [1] 8 9 9 7 8 9 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
x <- sample(100)
binSize <- 10
table(floor(x/binSize)*binSize)
```

Answer (score 1):

I created groups of equal size without using cut.

```
# number_of_groups_wanted  = number of rows / divisor in ceiling code  
# therefore divisor in ceiling code should be =  number of rows / number_of_groups_wanted, 
# divisor in ceiling code = (nrow(df)/number_of_groups_wanted)  
# min assigns every tied element to the lowest rank 
number_of_groups_wanted = 100 # put in the number of groups you want
df$group = ceiling(rank(df$var_to_group, ties.method = "min")/(nrow(df)/number_of_groups_wanted)) 

df$rank = rank(df$var_to_group, ties.method = "min") # this line is just used to check data
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
df$var_bin<- cut(df[['var']], breaks = Size(df$var/10), 
                 include.lowest=TRUE, labels=1:10)
```

Comment: R is giving me the error `could not find function "Size"`. Thoughts?

Comment: Try instead:  'nrow(df$var)/10'