# Splitting skewed data into even sized bins in R

Tags: r

I want to split this df into bins based on the variable Quality. However, it is extremely right skewed

```
     TSI2         YRI       Chromosome Quality
a1 0.03829518 0.050231431         22   0.860
a2 0.03110103 0.010192455         22   0.938
a3 0.03141379 0.060045625         22   0.848
```

This is a hist of Quality.

[image]

ll of the ways I have tried to bin the data so far have resulted in bins with very different numbers of samples in each.

```
totalResults$groups = cut(totalResults$Quality, 10)
```

Is there a way to force the bins to have even numbers of samples in each?

thanks

Comment: How many bins do you need?

Comment: It doesn't really matter so much, but 10 is what I've been doing.

Answer (score 0):

You get even counts if you split by quantiles  (use `?quantile`), but then the bins are of uneven length. This isn't a bad thing *per se*.

Answer (score 0):

Cut Numbers from ggplot2 has done the job well

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15277169/5784757

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/1.0.0/topics/cut_number